# Is it possible to get the list of all the routes in Hono framework?

Tags: node.js, hono

I need to get list of all the registered routes in Hono, similar to the one that Hapi's [`table()`](https://hapi.dev/api/?v=21.3.2#-servertablehost) API or Fastify plugin [`fastify-print-routes`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-print-routes).

Is there any internal API I can use to get this information? I cannot find anything from the official documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hono/dev` package has a `showRoutes` function that will log the routes to console. [Hono documentation](https://hono.dev/helpers/dev#showroutes)

It also has an `inspectRoutes` that's not in the documentation, but is used to generate the info in `showRoutes`. It returns the information you're looking for (path, method). [Source code](https://github.com/honojs/hono/blob/main/src/helper/dev/index.ts#L29)